# Trying to debug media print

Tags: css, debugging, printing, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to debug a media print stylesheet in Chrome. To this effect, I have followed a recommended practice, and checked the "emulate css media print" box under developer tools settings.

Unfortunately this is not working as expected: the page looks fine in the browser, but as soon as I switch to print preview or the actual print, the result is different.
My page is complex, with overlapping stylesheets, and I haven't been able to reproduce the issue on a simpler scenario on jsfiddle.

My question: is this a known issue with Chrome developer tools? If so, is there any workaround  that would help me debug my media print stylesheet?

To be more specific, my issue is related to background colors.

Comment: Did you try firefox? In the webdeveloper toolbar there is also a menu to enable and disable styles and check for print and handheld media types. Not sure if it's any better than the Chrome offer...

Comment: @rene thx. Could you be more specific? I am not familiar with the FF dev tools.

Comment: It is this extension http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/ that you need. That has an menu option called CSS that basically does the same what you describe. When I used it the rendering on screen did match the print....

Comment: @rene thanks again, I'll try that. As I was investigating the issue, I realized that it might actually be related to the way browsers handle background printing rules.

Comment: Hmmm, as far as I recall background colors where not in play in my scenario so I might have navigated you to an dead-end...

Answer (score 2):

ok, I think I found the reason why this is happening.

By default, browsers are set to ignore background colors for print. However, when I am emulating css media print, it seems that Chrome doesn't take into account such browser settings.

Now that I know where to look, the issue is easy to reproduce:

http://jsfiddle.net/rK7aX/

```
@media print {
  div {background-color:green;}
}
```

In the above example, the print preview will have a white background. The browser view with emulated media print will show a green text background.

Comment: By chance, did you found differences in layout too? I'm having problems with divs and tables width...

Comment: I didn't. But that wouldn't surprise me if the device width set in the browser is different from your print page width.

Comment: (so it's probably caused by CSS for the breakpoint one smaller than desktop size)